# How to do yoyo animation in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I know there is `repeat()` method on `AnimationController` but it always starts from the start.

Is there a built-in way to do one forward and one reverse animation, and to repeat that?

Thank you

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The [`repeat`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController/repeat.html) method supports the `reverse` optional named argument, so you can write

```
animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
```

This is the modern, simple solution.

Comment: Absolutely, the Flutter framework is constantly evolving, so something that was difficult to achieve and required cumbersome code (see Remi's answer that was the only solution a while ago) is now just a named parameter.

Comment: how do I repeat once

Comment: I suggest you open another question @PembaTamang, that way it can get more visibility.

Comment: One solution could be to add a status listener and count the status changes manually (see Remi's answer for inspiration), but there might be a more elegant way of doing that, so I recommend you open a new question

Comment: I did it with chaining the tween animations one forward and one reverse. Anyways thanks for your reply.

Comment: oh yes, that makes much more sense!

Comment: Can you add full example?

Comment: @giorgio79 If you re looking for tween sequence its similar to this 
`[
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1 - dynamicEndVal), weight: 75.0),
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1 - dynamicEndVal, end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
      ]`

Answer (score 33):

You can listen to the status of an animation using `addStatusListener`. And on animation end reverse it.

```
final AnimationController c;
...
c.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    c.reverse();
  }
  else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
    c.forward();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. that is how I did it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an even simpler solution using the MirrorAnimation widget from the [simple_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations) package.

With this you don't even have to create an AnimationController. There's also a LoopAnimation widget for running the animation continuously in one direction.

```
return MirrorAnimation(
      builder: (context, child, double value) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: pi * value,
          child: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
        );
      },
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 2),

    );
```